# Date format with [20th] suffix

Tags: java, android, date, date-formatting

How can I  convert **yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss** format into **November, 20th 2013.** format for display purpose?

Thanks.

Comment: what I found was patches. Like array of th,ed  etc. and I  have to append. them as per date.

Comment: Post your code which you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

You need this utility method to append `th` or `nd`, I didn't wrote it, I copied from somewhere into my code (don't remember now):

```
public class NumberUtils {
    public static String ordinal(int i) {
        String[] sufixes = new String[] { "th", "st", "nd", "rd", "th", "th",
            "th", "th", "th", "th" };
        switch (i % 100) {
        case 11:
        case 12:
        case 13:
        return i + "th";
        default:
            return i + sufixes[i % 10];
        }
    }
}
```

Combine it with other answers to get desired result.

Answer (score 0):

```
    long yourmilliseconds =System.currentTimeMillis();
                             SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS",Locale.US);
                             GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Central"));
                             calendar.setTimeInMillis(yourmilliseconds);
                                 time1=sdf.format(calendar.getTime());

 time1 = time1.substring(0, time1.indexOf(","));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
SimpleDateFormat desiredFormat =new SimpleDateFormat("EEE,dd-MMM-yyyy");    
Date dt = sourceFormat.parse(your_date);
String desiredDateString = desiredFormat.format(dt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DateFormat inputFormat = new DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
DateFormat outputFormat = new DateFormat("MMMM, dd yyyy");

Date date = inputFormat.parse("2013-11-28 00:52:19");
System.out.println(outputFormat.format(date));
```

You can use [this document](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar.

```
    SimpleDateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    Date date=df.parse("2013-11-20 12:00:00");
    df=new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM, dd'th' yyyy");
    System.out.println(df.format(date));
```

Out put

```
    November, 20th 2013
```